# Issue: JavaScript errors not being sent to New Relic in custom instance of visualCoding2-scratch

Tags: reactjs, performance, monitoring, newrelic, mit-scratch

I have set up Browser monitoring in my custom instance of visualCoding2(scratch) with some customizations. I am using New Relic to track JavaScript errors. However, the JS errors are not being sent to New Relic. I followed the JavaScript copy-paste method to configure it. The application has been running on my localhost for almost a day, but when I navigate to the "browser applications > JS errors" section in New Relic, nothing shows up. Strangely, other front-end monitoring aspects like page views are being measured correctly.

I need assistance in reflecting on these JS errors and warnings inside New Relic. Here are the steps I have already taken:

1. Ensured that the script tags are placed at the top of the head section.
2. Confirmed that other browser functionality, such as Ajax calls and Session Traces, is working correctly.

Any guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.